# How can access a VIEW in Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-layout, kotlin

I am working with Platform View in Flutter and I want to return a VIEW in my `getView()` constructor.
I have an `.xml` file with the View group that I want to return to in this. My question is how to return this since my constructor returns a VIEW.
That is the sample code:

```
internal class SBNativeView(context: Context, id: Int, creationParams: Map<String?, Any?>?) : PlatformView, AppCompatActivity() {
    private val textView: TextView

override fun getView(): View {
    return textView
}

override fun dispose() {}

init {
    textView = TextView(context)
    textView.textSize = 72f
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
    textView.text = "Rendered on a native Android view (id: $id)"
}
}
```

I need return this view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/loginConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textlayout_login_user_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_login_user_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="UserID"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textlayout_login_nickname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textlayout_login_user_id">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_login_nickname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nickname"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button_login_connect"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="#774df2"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="Connect"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textlayout_login_nickname"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How Can I return this view in getView()?

Comment: Are you trying to return view to Flutter side?

Comment: No, the view from the native side towards flutter. I was using this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views?tab=android-platform-views-kotlin-tab

Comment: I want something similar? @RicharC293 did you find any solution?